# o_number Function Is genarting exponatial out put if the number is morethan 15 digit

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select to_number('5131427328503192','9999999999999999') 
from dual
```

**output:** 5.13142732850319E15

How I can make the output as-is number

Comment: What database do you use ?
looks ok to me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c17fb88294d21501b4a4c70cc97b48af

Comment: I use oracle database , when the number is more than 16 digit it is creating this problem,

Comment: What tool do you use ? SQL Developer ?

Comment: this issue is tool independent , i was using this code inside a plsql program and executing the program

Answer (score 1):

A number is stored as binary data and is **NEVER** stored in the database with any particular (human-readable) formatting.

How the number is formatted is a function of the client application that you use to connect to the database.

In SQL*Plus, you can use:

```sql
SET NUMFORMAT 9999999999999999999990.9999999999999
```

In other client applications you can check the settings/preferences to see if they support a default number format and change that.

#### However

If you want a specific format then the most reliable solution is to convert your (unformatted) number to a formatted string using `TO_CHAR` with an explicit format model:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         to_number('5131427328503192','9999999999999999'),
         'fm999999999999999990'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```